# Binary file output for fixed length string

Tags: vb.net, binaryfiles

I am trying to write a binary file which also has a string which i want to have as fixed length in vb.net. I tried lset, padleft in debug, the value returned is correct but in the output file, the first character before the string is the fixed length i specified. why does the binary writer write the additional char ?

Comment: I don't know... Have you tried googling it or looking in the MSDN Documentation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#Anchor_2

Comment: Have you thought of that it might be the reason to why the String is _fixed length/length-prefixed_?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if if you don't want or need the length byte you can call Write with a Char [] array instead of a String